# Tiling a rectangle with weighted cells (min-max problem)

Tags: combinatorial-geometry, approximation-algorithms, tiling, weights, covering

I have been struggling with a research problem. The problem can be formalized as follows:

Given a $n\times m$ matrix $A$ containing cells with non-negative integer values, partition it in $J$ rectangles, such that each non-zero cell is covered **once** (non overlapping cover), and zero cell may or may not be covered by a rectangle. Given that weight of a rectangle is $a \cdot\text{perimeter}$ + $b\cdot \text{sum_of_cell_values_inside}$, design an algorithm which minimizes the maximum weight of a rectangle.

Ideally we are seeking for an approximation algorithm with at most a poly-logarithmic cost in terms of n or m. That said, ideally, we would like an approximation algorithm with competitive ratio=$2$ and $O(n\log n+m\log m)$ time complexity.

I hope anyone can give us some leads for solving this problem

> Comments:
>
> - It is allowed that either a or b is equal to 0, but not both of them. Setting one of these constants to zero simplifies the problem, so we are actually interested in the general case, 0 < a, b <= 1. Partition means that all the positive cells are covered exactly once, and zero cells are covered at most once.
> - J<< n and a and b are just weights whose values range between 0 and 1. That is 0<= a,b <=1
> - The matrix is sparse, that is the number of non-zero elements in the matrix is O(nlogn + mlogm)

Comment: Presumably $J$ is small? Otherwise the solution would be to enclose each cell in its own square...

Comment: And presumably $a > 0$, otherwise all covers have equal weight.

Comment: yes J is small. That is J<< n and a and b are just weights whose values range between 0 and 1. That is 0<= a,b <=1

Comment: @Joseph: a>0 is not needed as we want to minimize the maximum weight of a rectangle and not the total sum, so the question makes sense in this case as well.

Comment: @domotorp: Oh, you are right. Thanks!

Comment: @SaSa: what do you mean by partition? imo in a partition every cell is covered exactly once. do you want every cell covered at most once (and at least once if it's positive)? also, do you know the answer for a=0 or b=0?

Comment: I am Sasa's collaborator, and I'll try to clarify the problem statement. @domotorp: It is allowed that either a or b is equal to 0, but not both of them. Setting one of these constants to zero simplifies the problem, so we are actually interested in the general case, 0 < a, b <= 1. Partition means that all the positive cells are covered exactly once, and zero cells are covered at most once.

Comment: Thank you everyone .. any insights shed on this problem is very much appreciated. Thank you again :)

Comment: There is one more thing, which we implied, but did not state explicitly. The matrix is sparse.

Comment: What precisely do you mean by "sparse"? A constant number of entries in each row and column? At most $m+n$ entries in total? Or why would the total number of entries not appear in the runtime? (And edit the problem rather than posting an answer)

(And the upper bound $a,b<1$ seems to be irrelevant.)